# openpyxl writing large file memory issue

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a 75col by 650k rows document using openpyxl write only workbook, which is said to bear near constant memory footprint, but after a while I get 17.2GB memory usage in activity monitor, here's the code I'm using, am I doing something wrong?

```
def testOPENPYXL():
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook(write_only=True)
    ws = wb.create_sheet()
    for irow in range(650000):
        ws.append(['%d' % i for i in range(75)])
    path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/test/test.xlsx")
    wb.save(path)
```

Comment: It's Python 3.4.3

Comment: But what's the point in writing a huge XL file which you wont be able to open afterwards if it's so big that it wont fit in memory?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi exporting big database chunk into excel. The output document is about 200mb, the problem is the memory consumption while creating said file.

Comment: Oh. Thats quite reasonable.

Comment: FWIW openpyxl currently (2.4) uses about 8 times as much memory for files as MS Excel 2016.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simple solution is to install `lxml` we have a shim in openpyxl that mimics lxml's streaming writer but it isn't as memory efficient.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how lxml relates to creating excel files, is there any code snippets for using it?

Comment: Just install it and it gets used automatically.

Comment: What sorcery is this, installing lxml actually reduced the memory usage to a constant 40.1MB. Thank you!

Comment: See `lxml.etree.xmlfile` lxml can stream the XML to a buffer. Unfortunately the standard library doesn't have an equivalent and our replacement isn't suitable for such large files (XML is a great way to waste memory).

Comment: @CharlieClark, is this fix still working nowadays? With latest versions from both `openpyxl` (used by `pandas` internally) and `lxml` (inside a virtualenv), my server was consuming 40GB of memory and the process lasted for 6 hours before I killed it.

Comment: @thelawnmowerman `dataframe_to_rows` method from `openpyxl` may help